# Can a countable number of intersections of subsets or their complements be the null set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $$A_i \subseteq X, \ i\in \mathbb{N}$$

be arbitrary subsets of X.

Define

$$\mathcal{F}= \{ \cap_{i = 1}^\infty C_i \mid C_i = A_i \text{ or } C_i = A_i^c \}$$

Is it true that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$?

I tried to construct counter examples for this but could not.

EDIT: Another way to put the question is "Is it possible to pick $A_i$ such that $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$?".

I was not able to come up with counter-examples even considering the simple case of $X=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ is countable, then $\mathcal{F}$ must contain $\emptyset$; simply take $C_i$ to be whichever of $A_i$ and $A_i^c$ does not contain the $i$th element of $X$.

But if $X$ is uncountable, we can do it. Let $X$ be the Cantor set (if you're unfamiliar with the Cantor set, Google knows). For convenience, think of $X$ as a subset of the interval $[0,1]$ (even though we're treating it as a space of its own). Now, let $A_0 = X$, $A_1 = [0,\frac{1}{2}] \cap X$, $A_2 = ([0,\frac{1}{4}] \cup [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}]) \cap X$, and so on - all I'm doing is taking $A_i$ to be the leftmost of each pair of intervals of the Cantor set constructed at stage $i$. So $A_i^c$ will be the rest of those intervals.

Now, both $A_i$ and $A_i^c$ are nonempty closed sets, and if $i < j$ then $A_i \cap A_j$ and $A_i \cap A_j^c$ are both nonempty closed sets. So $\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty}C_i$ contains an infinite intersection of nested, nonempty closed sets; by compactness, this is nonempty.

Comment: Nice solution, +1!